# Get Views in a Table Row Android

Tags: android

```
for (int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {         
 final TableRow tr = new TableRow(referenceActivity);
 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) referenceActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View rowData = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.categoryadapter, null);
 final ImageView lPic = (ImageView) rowData.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 final ImageView rPic = (ImageView) rowData.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
 TextView category = (TextView) rowData.findViewById(R.id.textView_category);
 tr.addView(rowData);
 tv.addView(tr);            
}
```

If i click on a row, i want to change the images in ImageView.So I want to get the all three views ( two ImageView and one TextView ) in the row.
            How can i get the views in row?

Answer (score 1):

set one `id` to you `TableRow` while creating and every where you want get That just get that with following code.

```
TableRow tr = findViewById(yourId);
```

and for getting your imageView

```
ImageView iv =(ImageView ) tr.getChildAt(0); // 0 is imageView position in tableRow 
                                             // change that with your need
```

and if you add View directly you can try:

```
   ImageView iv = tr.findViewById(R.id.imageID);
```

Comment: i got row. i need to get the views inside the row.

Comment: @selva use setTag and getTag for views

Comment: @shayan I tried by using tr.getChildAt(). But i didn't get. Because I adds the view in row. I am not add the imageview directly in row.

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right when i am click on image. If i click on a row how can i get the views present in the row?